# why can't I drag rest of box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to solve the jquery draggable, there is code that retrieve information from database, each information show in each BOX from each row of database.

like this...

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');

$product_id=$_POST['selector'];
$N = count($product_id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product where product_id='$product_id[$i]'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      { ?>
      <div id="draggable" style="width:300px; height:200px">
      <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">product id</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input name="member_id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo  $row['product_id'] ?>" />
        <input name="firstname[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['product_name'] ?>" />
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">product category</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input name="lastname[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['product_category'] ?>" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div></div>

      <?php 
      }
}

?>
<input name="" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
</div></div>
```

In jquery

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

Now I want to use draggable of each box, as you can see in the code where it said id="draggable",

The draggable is works great and I only be able to drag **FIRST BOX** but they are more then one boxes and I won't be able to drag rest of boxes, is only works first box, why is not working rest of boxes!

what did I went wrong!

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Change the draggable ID to a Class.  The .draggable() is only being applied to the first because duplicate IDs are invalid.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      { ?>
      <div class="draggable" style="width:300px; height:200px">
      <div class="thumbnail">
...

$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
});
```